# ¿Como obtengo el peso de un archivo con python?

Tags: python, archivo

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede obtener el tamaño de un archivo ".txt" en Python, por ejemplo en bytes. He estado mirando en Internet y no encuentro método alguno que me sea útil para esto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pruebe usar `import os`:

```
import os
sizefile = os.stat('archivo.txt').st_size
print(sizefile)
```

o

```
sizefile = os.path.getsize('C:\\user\\folder\\archivo.txt')
print(sizefile)
```

Nota: con el método `stat` puede obtener multiples características de sistema de un archivo. Puede ver un poco mas al detalle en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat).

Comment: Si alguien se pregunta si hay diferencias: `os.path.getsize()` básicamente lo que hace es llamar a `os.stat().st_size`

Comment: y si fuera un directorio? cómo itero entre todos los archivos para validar su peso?

Comment: @Jefferson es fácil, con un `for` loop. Investigue acerca de `os.listdir` o `os.scandir` o `os.walk`.